# How do I replace multiple different strings in Pandas dataframe column with one common string value?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column and its string values as follows:

```
Aircraft Type
Boeing 777
777-200
B777
B777-300ER
777-312
```

I want to replace all string values with 'Boeing 777', however I have multiple separate instances of the Boeing 777 aircraft represented in the data in slightly different formats. How would I write a code that replaces all instances where a string contains '777' with 'Boeing 777'? My issue is that the Boeing 777 aircraft is represented in over 30 different formats, the data example above is just a subset. The only common theme is all formats include '777'.

I want the final output to look like this:

```
Aircraft Type
Boeing 777
Boeing 777
Boeing 777
Boeing 777
```

I tried the following code:

```
commerical_df['Model'].replace({'B777':'Boeing 777', '777-300ER':'Boeing 777'})
```

But again, the issue is I have over 30 different values that I would need to manually find and replace, which is cumbersome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
commerical_df.loc[commerical_df['Model'].str.contains('777'), 'Model'] = 'Boeing 777'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to conditionally check if the string `777` is present and then convert it to `Boeing 777`

**Note**
I added another row which doesn't contain `777` to show the solution works:

```
# Print original dataframe
print(df)
  Aircraft Type
0    Boeing 777
1       777-200
2          B777
3    B777-300ER
4       777-312
5           888
```

```
df['Aircraft Type'] = np.where(df['Aircraft Type'].str.contains('777'), 
                               'Boeing 777', 
                               df['Aircraft Type'])
```

---

```
print(df)
  Aircraft Type
0    Boeing 777
1    Boeing 777
2    Boeing 777
3    Boeing 777
4    Boeing 777
5           888
```